# How is deception analyzed in game theory?

Tags: game-theory

How is deception analyzed in game theory? A player can have incorrect information, instead of imperfect information or incomplete information.

Comment: I think that the question is too general. It really depends on the model and the source of information. For example, consider two players that play a one-shot game but don't know which one (chosen by nature). Instead, each player privately receives a signal which gives the true state w.p. $p$ and otherwise the wrong state. Given the signal, each player chooses his strategy conditioning on the signal he received (which might be incorrect...)

Comment: Maybe start with the theory of Cheap Talk